# can not authenticate google mysql command-line tools

Tags: mysql, cloud

I am trying to use Google Mysql Cloud. I have problem to authenticate google command-line tools. in google web site ( https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline ) they said I can download the command line tool and authenticate by using:

```
./google_sql.sh instance
```

This is a linux command, I can not use it in windows. Every time I use this command, windows will try to ask me what app I want to use to open this file.

I download a Cygwin to run the script, but I got a error like this:

```
Unable to access jarfile /d/google_sql.jar
```

really have no idea.

anyone can help me?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't neet to install Cygwin to run the script. In fact you don't need run Linux shell script, the one with .sh extension in Windows environment.

In zip file for Google Cloud SQL Command Line Tool there is a Windows Command batch file with .cmd extension.
You execute it like this:

**google_sql** appname:sqlinstancename

You don't need to put .cmd extension and don't forget to put project ID string and colon before sql instance name.

Command and its output is something like this:
    C:\google_sql_tool>google_sql appname:sqlinstancename
    Please authorize Google SQL Service for your Google Account at:
    http://.*/****** *Web page google directs you to get authorization code*
    Enter Authorization Code:***********long authorization code, paste here***********
    sql>